# Как проверить символ строки цифра или буква?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Есть строка требуется разделить на два массива. Один массив цифр а второй - букв. С распределением то я разберусь а вот как проверить символ строки цифра или буква? Может что то типа `isDigit(ch)` или `isAlphabet(ch)`

Comment: А в pascalabc.net `in` (оператор вхождения в множество) для `Char` работает?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел функцию которая решает этот вопрос. Статичный метод класса char: `Char.isdigit(char)` и `char.isLetter(char)`

Answer (score 0):

На `FreePascal`, нет под рукой `abc.net`, переделать думаю не сложно:

```
program split_symbols;

{$MODE OBJFPC}

uses
    SysUtils;

var
    s: string;
    symbols: array of char;
    numbers: array of integer;
    i: integer;
    num: integer;
    si, ni: integer;

begin
    s := '12abc34d9ef5';

    si := 0;
    ni := 0;
    for i := 1 to Length(s) do
        try
            begin
                num := StrToInt(s[i]);
                Inc(ni);
                SetLength(numbers, ni);
                numbers[ni - 1] := num;
            end;
        except on E: EConvertError do
            begin
                Inc(si);
                SetLength(symbols, si);
                symbols[si - 1] := s[i];
            end;
        end;

    write('numbers:');
    for i := low(numbers) to high(numbers) do
        write(numbers[i]:2);

    writeln();

    write('symbols:');
    for i := low(symbols) to high(symbols) do
        write(symbols[i]:2);
end.
```

**Вывод**

```
numbers: 1 2 3 4 9 5
symbols: a b c d e f
```

Comment: Использование исключений для такой задачи - нонсенс

Comment: Ваш вариант не отделит буквы от прочих символов